# Harvest API-Call to undefined method HarvestAPI::getActiveProjects

Tags: php, api, harvest

I am trying to retrieve the project names for all the active projects. I was following the documentation and code given over here[Harvest API](http://mdbitz.com/harvest-api/examples/using-the-advanced-reporting-functions-of-harvestreports/). But it throws an error **Call to undefined method HarvestAPI::getActiveProjects** .Here is the code which I have written

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/HarvestAPI.php');

/* Register Auto Loader */
spl_autoload_register(array('HarvestAPI', 'autoload'));

$api = new HarvestAPI();
$api->setUser( $user );
$api->setPassword( $password );
$api->setAccount($account );

$api->setRetryMode( HarvestAPI::RETRY );
$api->setSSL(true);

$result = $api->getActiveProjects();
 foreach( $result->data as $project ) {
        echo $project->name;
    }
?>
```

P.S. I have administrator access for the account. So, I should be able to view all project titles

Answer (score 0):

Look into HarvestAPI.php you will see that there is no method called `getActiveProjects`

Use this one

```
public function getProjects( $updated_since = null ) 
{
    $url = "projects" . $this->appendUpdatedSinceParam( $updated_since );
    return $this->performGET( $url, true );
}
```

Comment: Where would one add the login credentials?